# Is it valid to use the #define preprocessor directive inside an #if in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

Could I use `#define` [preprocessor directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) inside `#if` and `#endif`, in C# ?

e.g.

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT && !__ANDROID__ && !__IOS__ 
#define SupportsMutex
#endif
```

It looks like it works, but I need to be sure. There is a lot written about this, but most of the time in the context of C and not C# - the preprocessor directives a in C# far more limited.

Visual Studio's highlighting seems to support it, but it this really valid according to the language / compiler specs?

The [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) gives the following note:

> The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as static members of a class or struct. If you have several such constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold them.

I need this because using  `#if !SILVERLIGHT && !__ANDROID__ && !__IOS__` multiple times is difficult to manage.

Of course we could also add `SupportsMutex` to the "conditional compilation symbols" of a project, but this is more difficult to manage and less transparant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Looking at the [C# specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) a particular example of this usage is given in section **2.5.3 Declaration directives** and deemed as valid:

```
#define Enterprise
#if Professional || Enterprise  
   #define Advanced
#endif 
namespace Megacorp.Data 
{
    #if Advanced    
    class PivotTable {...}  
    #endif 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! quickly found!